# Is it possible to set up a subdomain and link to it from the main site?

Tags: url, domains

I have a store hosted on big cartel which I want to set up as a subdomain on my website. Something like: `http://store.mysite.com`

Is it possible to do this somehow?

If so, how do links to the subdomain work? Would a link to `store.mysite.com/product1.html` be the same as `externalsite.com/product1.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may certainly set up a subdomain for your website.   To do so you need to:

- Find out the IP address or host name that your host (big cartel) uses internally for the store.
- In your DNS records for your domain create a record for `store.mysite.com`.  If you have an IP address from your host, then make it an `A` record.  If you have a host name, then make it a `CNAME` record.

Since only you can set up subdomains on your site, they are usually considered part of your site.  So linking your store on a subdomain would be fine and not the same as an external link.  In fact linking to your subdomain frequently will give search engines such as Google the confidence that the subdomain is really part of your site and not something that you set up for somebody else.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your help. If a page on your external site is 'www.BigCartel.com/products.html', would 'store.mySite.com/products.html' take you to the same page? Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: You might be able to configure the web server to redirect one link to the other.  However, if you don't do that then because the URLs are different, those are considered different pages (especially since they are on different domains).